# split large xml into small chunks

Tags: python, split, xml-parsing, lxml, large-files

We want to process large xml file around 6 GB.

Here we are reading the large xml into dataframe and then export it to csv file
we are using lxml with iterparse to read xml line by line and load it into dataframe.but this process is almost taking 6 minutes.

So we decide to split this xml into small chunks like 1GB each and then process it concurrently.

Can you suggest the fastest way of splitting this large xml files ?

I have already tried link https://gist.github.com/benallard/8042835 which is almost taking 8-10 just for splitting the file

The structure of my xml is as below. In real application we have almost 200 tags under  and there are almost 100000 records with  tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ACADEMICS>  
  <STUDENTS ASOF_DATE="11/21/2019" CREATE_DATE="11/22/2019" RECORDS="108881">      
    <STUDENT>      
      <NAME>JOHN</NAME>      
      <REGNUM>1000</REGNUM>      
      <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>      
      <ID>JH1</ID>
      <SHORT_STD_DESC>JOHN IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
    </STUDENT>
   <STUDENT>      
    <NAME>ADAM</NAME>      
    <REGNUM>1001</REGNUM>      
    <COUNTRY>FRANCE</COUNTRY>      
    <ID>AD2</ID>
    <SHORT_STD_DESC>ADAM IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
  </STUDENT>
  <STUDENT>      
    <NAME>PETER</NAME>      
    <REGNUM>1003</REGNUM>      
    <COUNTRY>BELGIUM</COUNTRY>      
    <ID>PE5</ID>
    <SHORT_STD_DESC>PETER IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
</STUDENT>
<STUDENT>      
    <NAME>ERIC</NAME>      
    <REGNUM>1006</REGNUM>      
    <COUNTRY>AUSTRALIA</COUNTRY>      
    <ID>ER7</ID>
    <SHORT_STD_DESC>ERIC IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
</STUDENT>
<STUDENT>      
    <NAME>NICHOLAS</NAME>      
    <REGNUM>1009</REGNUM>      
    <COUNTRY>GREECE</COUNTRY>      
    <ID>NI8</ID>
    <SHORT_STD_DESC>NICHOLAS IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
</STUDENT>
```

Comment: Don't use `.iterparse()` because it *still* builds the entire document tree in memory as it parses the input, but you don't even need the tree for anything. Splitting the document and reading smaller parts will not necessarily speed up the operation either. Using bespoke event-based parser to stream the file could be your best option, but for that you should show a meaningful part of your XML and point out which data you need to extract.

Comment: Hi Tomalak,

I have update the xml structure in my original post.
To keep it simple, here i have mentioned only 5 <STUDENT> records with only 5 attribute within it like <NAME>, <REGNUM>, <COUNTRY> etc.In real application we have almost 100000 records with <STUDENT> tag and 200 attributes within it.

Comment: *"[...] and point out which data you need to extract."*

Comment: We want to extract all 200 fields attributes.

Comment: The general approach is below. Test it with a few attributes only at first to get a feeling for it. If all attributes you need are direct children of `<STUDENT>`, then all you need to do is extend the column list.

Answer (score 0):

When we imagine a *minimal* parser, there is only a couple of events we need to react to when reading the XML file:

- An opening `<STUDENT>` is encountered: Prepare a new list so we can store the various values we will see.
- An opening `<NAME>`, `<REGNUM>` etc. is encountered: Find out into which slot this property value is supposed to go (the "current" slot).
- A piece of text is encountered: If this text belongs to a property we care for, write it to the current slot.
- A closing `</NAME>`, `</REGNUM>` etc. is encountered: Make note that any text that comes next is not interesting and should be ignored.
- A closing `</STUDENT>` is encountered: We are done with the current student and can output all the data we have collected.

With that in mind we can create a SAX event handler that implements this idea:

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class StudentReader(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        self.column_order = 'ID,NAME,REGNUM,COUNTRY,SHORT_STD_DESC'
        self.current_student = None
        self.current_idx = None
        self.mapping = {key: idx for idx, key in enumerate(self.column_order.split(','))}
        self.num_cols = len(self.mapping)
        self.callback = callback

    def startElement(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'STUDENT':
            # new student with correct number of columns
            self.current_student = [''] * self.num_cols
        elif tag in self.mapping:
            # which column are we writing to?
            self.current_idx = self.mapping[tag]
        else:
            self.current_idx = None

    def endElement(self, tag):
        if tag == 'STUDENT':
            if self.callback is not None:
                # when we have a callback, call it
                self.callback(self.current_student)
            else:
                # without a callback, just print to console (for debugging)
                print(self.current_student)
        elif tag in self.mapping:
            self.current_idx = None

    def characters(self, data):
        if self.current_idx is not None:
            self.current_student[self.current_idx] += data
```

Nothing else needs to be retained, no tree needs to be built, we can do this *while* reading the input XML. This will be fast and use *very* little memory.

Now we can create a SAX parser and give it a `StudentReader` instance:

```
import xml.sax

handler = StudentReader()
xml.sax.parse('data.xml', handler)
```

...which will print lists to the console:

```
['JH1', 'JOHN', '1000', 'USA', 'JOHN IS A GOOD STUDENT']
['AD2', 'ADAM', '1001', 'FRANCE', 'ADAM IS A GOOD STUDENT']
['PE5', 'PETER', '1003', 'BELGIUM', 'PETER IS A GOOD STUDENT']
['ER7', 'ERIC', '1006', 'AUSTRALIA', 'ERIC IS A GOOD STUDENT']
['NI8', 'NICHOLAS', '1009', 'GREECE', 'NICHOLAS IS A GOOD STUDENT']
```

But maybe it's more interesting to write the data to a CSV file, for example.

That's what the `callback` argument in our `StudentReader` is for - we could pass those lists directly to a CSV writer, so it can write an output file *while* the input file is being processed.

```
import csv
import xml.sax

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=';')

    handler = StudentReader(writer.writerow)

    xml.sax.parse('data.xml', handler)
```

Of course you could also use a database command in the callback, or whatever you need.

Comment: Hi Tomalak,

That was really helpful. Now i can process the file in 8 minutes and that too with keeping the memory low.
Not sure if still there is a scope of improvement to make it less then 8 minutes. Please advice.
Also we are having a performance issue while dumping same file data into MongoDB. I have raised a ticket on that as below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931259/pymongo-bulk-write-perform-very-slow
Just have alook and may be you can help us on that as well

Comment: Hi Tomalak, 

Also as you can see we have ASOF_DATE="11/21/2019" attributes for STUDENTS tag. Can you please let me know how can i fetch this ASOF_DATE value using above code suggested by you ?

Comment: @user1957116 Re-read the text I wrote, I answered this question (in a comment to your question). Read the code. Understand what it does. If you blindly copy and run code from the Internet that somebody else wrote and that you don't fully understand, then you have a problem.

Comment: Also, it's more work than necessary to write things to a CSV file and then import that CSV into MongoDB. Import the data directly into MongoDB by writing a different callback.